# splitting a string into different columns in python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a string like :

```
"probability": {"go": 0.63549300785454799, "stand": 0.15739544829291019, "stop": 0.36450699214545207}, "label": "go"
```

Of this string, i want to extract only the part after **'**}, "**'**, i.e.

```
"label": "go"
```

This string is generated in a loop, hence have to perform this action within the loop itself. Also, the length of the different parts of the string is not constant. 
How may I extract the desired part of the string?

Comment: you mean like `s.split('}, ')[1]`?

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you're solving the wrong problem here. It looks like your string is a substring of some JSON document, which you should be handling using actual JSON tools.

Comment: @EdChum: thanks, it served the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thestring = '"probability": {"go": 0.63549300785454799, "stand": 0.15739544829291019, "stop": 0.36450699214545207}, "label": "go"'
print thestring.split('}, ')[1]
```

Output:

```
"label": "go"
```

Comment: Looks good but `print` is a function in python 3.  Use either `print(thestring.split('}, ')[1])` or just plain `thestring.split('}, ')[1]`.